# Why is "rails generate controller" not actually doing anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.0.  I wanted to generate a controller so I thought I'd use the "rails generate controller" command.  However, although it says it created the controller (as well as a bunch of other files) they are not on my file system.  See the output and the ls command below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
localhost:cindex davea$ rails generate controller UserNotifications
Running via Spring preloader in process 97745
      create  app/controllers/user_notifications_controller.rb
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/user_notifications
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/controllers/user_notifications_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/user_notifications_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/user_notifications.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/user_notifications.scss
localhost:cindex davea$ vim app/controllers/
application_controller.rb  concerns/                  pages_controller.rb
localhost:cindex davea$ ls app/controllers/user_notifications_controller.rb
ls: cannot access 'app/controllers/user_notifications_controller.rb': No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you checked the other files? are they created? permissions on the folder, also which version of rails?

Comment: Rails 5.0.4.  None of the files above is created.  Perms look good.  Root project is "drwxr-xr-x 19 davea staff  646 Aug 24 16:44"

Comment: Looks like the folder is read only for the `rails` command, run `sudo chmod -R 775 .`. and then try the command again. or if the command is available to `root` user you can run `sudo rails g ControllerName`

Comment: Something very weird\

Comment: That's why I asked the question!